# What software can I use to automatically insert a statement into multiple documents?

Tags: linux, windows, autonomy

This is a simple scenario, the scale is 100 times bigger.
Doc 1 has 3 statements.
These statements will have to be repeated in 100 other documents.
Can anyone share what software(linux or any software in windows) we can use to automatically update the relevant statements into the 100 documents?

Currently looking for something similar as this will greatly enhance productivity without the need to keep manually repeating.

Comment: What document format?  PDF, Word, plain text?  Modifying 100 documents by hand may still be easier than getting some software, testing it, and running it against a mere 100 documents.

Comment: Why did you add the "Autonomy" tag? Is it about their software?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc word doc

Comment: @Dominique Sorry, I think I used the wrong tag.